# Set ant bootclasspath: JDK 1.7 has a new javac warning for setting an older source without bootclasspath

Tags: java, ant, javac, java-7

How do I set the ant bootclasspath in conjunction with -source 1.5 -target 1.5?

How can this not be a hardcoded path to the 1.5 JDK? Can I set an environment variable to bootclasspath similar to how JAVA_HOME can be used from ant?

Ideally I would like to do something like set an environment variable or pass an argument to ant.

Comment: Actually, you only need the rt.jar of your 1.5 JRE, not the full JDK, I think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an illustration of how you might fetch the Java 5 boot classes location from an environment variable, then use it.

First, set the environment variable - say `JAVA5_BOOTCLASSES`.
The [`property` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) gives you access to the environment, then the `bootclasspath` argument of the [`javac` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) passes the setting to the compiler.

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="java5.boot.classpath" value="${env.JAVA5_BOOTCLASSES}" />

<javac source="1.5" target="1.5"
       bootclasspath="${java5.boot.classpath}"
       ...
/>
```

Note that if the environment variable is not set, Ant will ignore it and proceed without - so the compiler will fall back to the default boot classpath.

Another option, if appropriate, is to [*switch off the warnings*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#xlintwarnings), and not bother with the bootclasspath.  Something like

```
<javac srcdir= ... >
    <compilerarg arg="-Xlint:-options" />
</javac>
```

But that's likely to expose you to some subtle bugs.

Comment: You might would like to add executable property in javac task to point to JDK1.7 executable for making it more clearer

Comment: This is a really helpful answer but I'm not sure what to set `JAVA5_BOOTCLASSES` to if I'm building a jar for distribution. Wouldn't that require me to know paths on the machines of anyone who ever runs the jar?

Comment: @nickform - hopefully not.  The source/target/bootclasspath options are there for building backwards-compatible classes.  Once deployed the JAR should work anywhere, as long as the minimum version criterion is met.  Beyond that the bootclasspath at run time should not matter at build time.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noticing that variable `JAVA5_BOOTCLASSES` should contain all needed libraries not just rt.jar. In my case it was also jce.jar So it's good to set this variable using this simple snippet when in *nix environment:

```
export JAVA5_BOOTCLASSES=""
for i in /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/*.jar; do 
    export JAVA5_BOOTCLASSES=$JAVA5_BOOTCLASSES:$i
done
```