# Only have JavaSE 1.7 JRE but wish to compile for 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

```
I have Java SE 1.7.
javac = 1.7.0_79 
java version = "1.7.0_79"
Eclipse = Luna.
```

I want to compile at 1.6 level.
I use an Ant build script.

Ant record directive. Output below:

```
'-target'
'1.6'
'-g'
'-source'
'1.6'

...
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 warning
```

I get following error:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 at command line works as expected.

The following answers this question:

[bootclassloader-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260697/set-ant-bootclasspath-jdk-1-7-has-a-new-javac-warning-for-setting-an-older-sour#7355205)

Get the rt.jar from your final destination machine. bootclasspath must point to this rt.jar, somehow.

Comment: What *exact* Eclipse settings did you change? Please show a screenshot.

Comment: Duplicate of [Target JRE in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092284/target-jre-in-eclipse)

Comment: Think I asked wrong question. I have an ant script that I am using to build. I need to look at ant, correct?

Comment: javac  source="1.6" target="1.6" still no good...

Comment: javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 HelloWorld.java. Confirmed from command line that all works as expected using javac 1.7.0_79. Great...Now how to get Ant/Eclipse to the party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the ant file there is a javac target.
This has an option "target=
There you set "1.6"

If you have doubts what ant uses, start it with option -v this will ouput all actions to console.

about your warning, see:
https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source

Comment: Youhave another problem, like I have now. There is something unclean e.g JRE and JDK differently at yourmachine: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error